# How work addOrUpdateObjectsFromArray in Realm Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, realm

I have a DB:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsPks.png)

and I have an array:
 NSArray * array = @[@"1",@"text",@"text",@"0"];

How can I by the method of Relam addOrUpdateObjectsFromArray load array to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

[realm beginWriteTransaction];

[YourRModel createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:@{ 
@"id" : @(1),
@"name" : @"text",
@"value" : @"text",
@"isSend" : @"0" }];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

And don't forget:

```
#import "YourRModel.h"

@implementation YourRModel

+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"id";
}

@end
```